# What happens if the owner of the blue elfstones dies before passing them along?

Tags: shannara

So, according to legend, only a person who was given the blue elfstones willingly by the owner could use their magic. How is it then, that Allanon can give them to Shea? From what I remembered, the stones were lost and Allanon had to find them before giving them to Shea. Would the owners death free the stones to be used by the first person to come along?

EDIT:

In the *Genesis* series, we see Kirisin getting them from the spirit of the last owner(Pancea Rolt Gotrin) who had died in the time of faerie. In *Legends* series, we see Phryne get them from the spirit of her grandmother(the owner) who had only been dead a matter of hours. So, I'm asking what happens if the owner isn't powerful enough with magic to leave a spirit behind to give them?

Comment: Now I'm struggling to think of a time that what you're asking has happened or even been mentioned, so it may be unanswerable. I think I have the *World of Shannara* at home, it might help.

Comment: @MikeEdenfield: The one instance I can think of is the fact that Allanon has them at the beginning of *Sword* and gives them to Shea, but I don't remember how Allanon got them to begin with, or if it was even covered.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**tl;dr:** Based on the few pieces of evidence I could find, it seems like that either:

1. The requirement to pass the Elfstones on voluntarily isn't real, just a part of the legend, or
2. Once the current owner dies and can no longer pass them on, they become "fair game" for whoever finds them.

I tend to think #2 is more correct, but I don't know that we have any concrete evidence (e.g. someone trying and failing to use them) to conclusively say either way.

---

There have been a few instances in the novels where characters "find" the Elfstones after they have been lost for a long time. In those cases, the Elf who found them was able to use them later. For example:

- During the *Voyage of the Jerle Shannara* series, Ahren Elessedil finds the Blue Elfstones in Parkasia, presumably where they were lost by Kael Elessedil. Ahren is able to find and recover the Elfstones even though Kael is dead by that point.
- Other sets of Elfstones are found by

> Redden Ohmsford when he goes into the Forbidding during the *Dark Legacy* trilogy.

The Crimson Elfstones end up being used at one point, despite having been lost in for centuries. (We have no reason to think the Crimson Elfstones are substantially different from the Blue ones in this regard.)

Also, there seems to be a lot of effort to keep the Elfstones out of the wrong hands, for example:

- We know that use of the Elfstones requires Elven blood. This is why the Ohmsfords eventually had to give them to the Elessedils -- the Elven blood was too dilute in the Ohmsford line.
- We know that the Elfstones were a closely guarded treasure in the early days of the Elves (*Genesis* era and earlier).
- We know that when Wren was young, her parents left her the Blue Elfstones, disguised as simple rocks.

If ownership of the Elfstones had to be transferred from person to person, a lot of this would seems to be overkill; if no one can use them without their current owner voluntarily handing them off, there'd be no point in trying to steal them or take them by force.

Thus, it seems pretty likely that it *is* possible to obtain and use the Elfstones without the explicit blessing of their previous owner. In all cases we've seen this happen, the previous owner was dead, so it's likely that once this happens, the Elfstones are free for anyone of Elven blood to find them and use them.

Comment: I hadn't yet read *Dark Legacy*(SPOILERS YO. J/K). But between that, and *Voyage*(been a LONG while since I read it) I believe it's at least fair to say that if the owner days, the stones are fair game. But that does still leave the option that the willing pass down is just legend. I know he's getting close to being done with writing about Shannara. I hope that he covers this a bit.

Comment: I actually forgot how new *Dark Legacy* was, my bad!

Comment: LOL. Doesn't bother me. But others might.